# Synaptic Pointing Device. What is it used for and how can I delete it?

Tags: uninstall, synaptics-touchpad

What is Synaptic Pointing Device. What is it used for? Should I delete it? And how can I delete it?

I tried to delete it by going to C disk and deleting the folder with it. But since it starts pretty fast I was not able to close it in the Task Manager and then to delete its files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the driver of your touch pad / touch styck and related buttons, I wouldn't recommend uninstalling it.

http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Synaptics-Pointing-Device-Driver-5308-program.aspx

Comment: Can I prevent it from showing in the lower right corner?

Comment: Yes, you can hide it, see help here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/30031/windows-10-customize-taskbar-notification-area